# Top CSS selector not applying formatting on children elements

Tags: html, css

I am currently using http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ as my top level CSS. Assume that I can't change this.

So my top CSS level is something like this:

**base.css**

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline; 
}

div .target {
  ...
}
```

**index.html**

```
  <body>
   <div class="target">
      <strong>Please make me bold</strong>
      <i>Please make me italic</i>
   </div>
  </body>
```

For some reason `font: inherit;` does not allow formatting elements to be applied to my content i.e. `<strong>`, `<i>`, etc. I was hoping that I could use these formatting html tags within `.target` and have them render correctly with the current structure of my CSS. Is there any possible way to edit `div p` so that this works?

**jsFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/y4c3c9cb/6/

Note: Top selector (`html, body, div,...`) can't be moved, edited, and must stay in the top level position.

**EDIT** Children within my `.target` element will can be `i`, `strong`, `b` elements.

**EDIT 2**: Changed HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That reset implies that you set up rules for all these tags yourself. Since it includes `strong { font: inherit; }`, you have to add

```
strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Same for italic:

```
i {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

...and also complete rules for all the other tags that are in the reset rule, since otherwise everything will look the same.

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6nuogzg4/1/

Comment: Please see edit. I will potentially have `i`, `strong`, `b` elements in the div container.

Comment: so you have to add CSS rules for all these tags, as well as for h1, h2, h3, etc., ul, li etc. etc. etc. (i.e. all the tags in the reset rule). It's a *complete* reset which sets everything to a neutral default state...

Comment: @jimmyguestnow Its what reset essentially **does**. The intention behind reset is not just consistency across browsers but also to help keep the markup and presentation separate. It basically *un-styles* everything. Allowing you separately control how things *look* while respecting a good degree of semantics in your html.

Comment: just read Eric Meyer's notes at the page you linked: " ...I don't particularly recommend that you just use this in its unaltered state in your own projects.  It should be tweaked, edited, extended, and otherwise tuned to match your specific reset baseline. Fill in your preferred colors for the page, links, and so on. ..."

Comment: @AnkithAmtange Yeah I think fundamentally I don't get the motive behind a reset. I am a bit confused by "help keep the markup and presentation separate" and "Allowing you separately control how things look while respecting a good degree of semantics in your htm." Is part of the purpose for me to define what my project and I think `strong`, `i`, `b`, `h1` .. elements should *look* like? I don't get why one would want to remove styles from everything and build from there instead of just maintaining initial styles and building from there instead.

Comment: because the default rules vary between different browsers and OSs. That reset (together with a huge bunch of your own rules) will make sure that it really looks the same in *all* browsers.

Comment: ^^ and there is no literal separation in markup and presentation. You still resort to a HTML `tag` to define *presentation*. But how that particular tag is rendered or styled is under your complete control. You get define whats needed.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your css is setting elements like strong to inherit the font, so its going to inherit the font associated with p, which is non-bold.

Add font-weight: bold for strong.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `font-weight:bold;`. Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y4c3c9cb/3/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use this tapeworm. Use:

```
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 border: 0;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

instead.